# Deleting some blank pages from the document

Tags: blank-page

I'm using the [Legrand Orange Book](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) template and I notice some blank pages, but I'd like to delete them.

I had to remove the term `\thispagestyle{empty}` from the `main.tex` file, but it did not happen what I wanted.

To delete these blank pages should i modify the `main.tex` or `structure.tex`?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Where do these blank pages occur?

Comment: If these blank pages occur right before the start of a chapter, then a) that is to be expected, several document classes forces chapters to start on odd-numbered pages; and b) try adding `openany` to the class options.

Comment: @Torbjorn Exactly what I'm imagining. I believe there is a term that forces the existence of these pages.

Comment: Can `\cleardoublepage` influence something?

Comment: Did you try adding `openany` to the class options?

Comment: I added, but I have not seen result in the whole document. Maybe I have to compile more often.

Comment: openany (default for report)
openright (default for book)

Comment: I found something on this [site](https://texblog.org/2013/02/13/latex-documentclass-options-illustrated/#openright), but I can only try tomorrow

Comment: If you get an empty page with `openany` in effect, the problem will not be related to the start of a chapter, I guess. But if that is the case it's completely impossible for us to answer without more information, so you need to make a MWE demonstrating the problem.

Comment: IT'S OK. When possible, I report the code. Grateful.